# Solving a diophantine equation of second degree

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have to solve the equation $$\frac{n_1(3n_1-1)}{2}=\frac{n_2(3n_2-1)}{2}$$
and find out the couple $(x;y)\in\Bbb N^2$ for wich $|x-y|$ is minimised with $n_1≠n_2$. What I've thought so far is that when we write $ab = cd$, at least, $a$ or $b$ should divide $c$ or $d$, or, $c$ or $c$ or $d$ should divide $a$ or $b$. I know that's a bit confusing. By giving an example, we can write $$12=4.3=2.6$$

Here, $2|3$ and $3|6$. But I don't know if this property is always thrue or useful in this situation with $n_1(3n_1-1)=n_2(3n_2-1)$. How can I solve this equation?

Comment: The problem uses $n_1, n_2$ and then suddenly $x,y$. And where so $a,b,c,d$ come from suddenly?

Comment: I've wrote $(x;y)$ to be the couple for which $|n_1-n_2|$ is minimal and used $a,b,c,d$ to give a general definition about what I've thought. The $a,b,c,d$ is something general that I think, can help to solve the problem

Comment: If we are trying to minimize $|n_1-n_2|$ the answer is  $0$, and there are many couples. What are we minimizing?

Comment: Yes, you're right, forgot about precising $n_1≠n_2$.

Comment: @moray95 There are no integer solutions with $n_1 \ne n_2$, let alone positive integer solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $x$ and $y$ instead of subscripts. If the equality holds then $3x^2-3y^2-(x-y)=0$, or equivalently 
$$(x-y)\left(3(x+y)-1\right)=0.$$

There are no integers $x$ and $y$ such that $3(x+y)-1=0$. For if $3(x-y)-1=0$, then $3(x+y)=1$. But $3$ does not divide $1$.

Thus if $(x,y)$ is a  solution of the equation in integers, then $x=y$.

Comment: If $(x-y)\left(3(x+y)+1\right)=0$ then $x=y$ or $3x+3y+1=0$. So it's not forced that $x=y$.

Comment: @moray95 It is if we require $x,y\in\mathbb Z$ as usual for Diophantine equations.

Comment: No, haven't changed the sign it's just a typo. But you're right I got it know. Thanks